# Heroku deploy fails to load custom .bundle file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm having a lot of trouble googling this issue, as `bundler` keeps coming up. However, my issue is with a c library that I've bundled using `mkmf` and the [ruby c api](https://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/). I've compiled my c code into a file (e.g. `my_library.bundle`) and I've required it inside a helper with `require_relative "my_library"` without a problem.

The problem arrises when I deploy to heroku and I get the error:

```
2019-08-14T19:09:15.452530+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': cannot load such file -- /app/app/helpers/my_library (LoadError)
```

I can run `ls` and `cat` on my heroku app to verify the file is there and the contents match. When I run the application locally with `RAILS_ENV=production`, I also don't run into any issues. Also, running `heroku local web` runs fine on my machine.

Does this have something to do with my configs `autoload_paths`? My main issue is that I can't seem to debug this locally.

**EDIT:**
I've noticed that this problem arrises in dockerized instances, as well. It seems that something about containerization seems to be the problem. I've even tried creating a gem to contain the bundle following [this guide](https://github.com/andremedeiros/ruby-c-cheat-sheet), which works locally, but again has the same issue finding the file, but this time the path is relative to the gem, not my project. I'm still stumped on what is causing this issue.

Comment: Do you compile this on your local machine? I was under the impression that you'd need to compile the bundle on the machine you which to use it (e.g. can't compile on a mac, include, and deploy to heroku)

Comment: Run this on your Docker image to check which is the path of the library inside the image `docker run -it YOUR_IMAGE find . my_library`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jay-dorsey mentioned, the bundle did need to be compiled on the server that was deploying the application in order to be used. Both of the guides that I followed to create the gem had some misinformation.

1. The gem should contain only the source files, no compiled source files
2. The rakefile should reference `ext.lib_dir = "lib/my_library"` instead of the `ext` directory
3. The gemspec should add the `rake-compiler` development dependency BEFORE the other dependencies
4. The version files should NOT try to load the extension, as it's being used in the gemspec, which is called before the gem has a chance to be compiled by rake / bundler
5. `.bundle` files can't be read on linux machines

Answer (score 0):

According to the error that you posted, it seems that Docker doesn't point to the correct path `cannot load such file -- /app/app/helpers/my_library`. If that is correct, you should explicitly specify the working directory in your Dockerfile.

`WORKDIR /path/to/project`

After that, just rebuild the image.

Now, if this doesn't work, you can check `autoload_paths` in your project or customize bootsnap to avoid error in autoloading paths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error I snagged was from Heroku, so that's the correct path. As for `autoload_paths`, I've double checked, but every directory under `/app` is included.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have the entire `my_library` as a *local gem* and point your Gemfile to it.
Roughly, the outline would be as follows:

1. Place the entire code for `my_library` in  directory within your app, say `fixtures` (which is at the same level as your Gemfile.)

   ```
   app/
     ...
   fixtures/
     my_library/
       ext/
         ...
       lib/
         ...
       my_library.gemspec
       Rakefile
   Gemfile
   ```
2. Point your Gemfile to the `my_library` gem:

   ```
   gem 'my_library', path: 'fixtures/my_library'
   ```
3. Then simply update your `Gemfile.lock` by running

   ```
   bundle update
   ```